# How can I make a random string generator with flexible criteria?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on an android app (Java) and I need a string generator.I do not know how to make the allowed chars enable and disable them. Normaly you would write this code :

```
    private static final String CHAR_LOWER = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private static final String CHAR_UPPER = CHAR_LOWER.toUpperCase();
    private static final String NUMBER = "0123456789";

    private static final String DATA_FOR_RANDOM_STRING = CHAR_LOWER + CHAR_UPPER + NUMBER;
    private static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(generateRandomString(10));
        }

    }

    public static String generateRandomString(int length) {
        if (length < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            
            int rndCharAt = random.nextInt(DATA_FOR_RANDOM_STRING.length());
            char rndChar = DATA_FOR_RANDOM_STRING.charAt(rndCharAt);

            sb.append(rndChar);

        }

        return sb.toString();

}
```

,but you can not change the allowed chars with, for example a switch.
How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by : "change the allowed chars with, for example a switch" ?  you can add as input to the method "generateRandomString(int len, String DataChars)", and chose from it.  so when you call "generateRandomString" you can give what you want. is that what you mean ?

Comment: At first I wrote ```public static final string``` = the used/allowed characters.This is what I want to change with a switch etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the String of symbols (from where you choose the random characters) as input to the method `generateRandomString(int len, String DataChars)`.  and change the code in `generateRandomString` to work with `DataChars`.
2. You can call `generateRandomString` with any Strings you want.
3. You can use `switch` (as you asked) to choose what group of symbols to use.

The source code below, use these three points as follow:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Main
{
    private static final String CHAR_LOWER = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private static final String CHAR_UPPER = CHAR_LOWER.toUpperCase();
    private static final String NUMBER = "0123456789";
    private static final String DATA_FOR_RANDOM_STRING = CHAR_LOWER + CHAR_UPPER + NUMBER;
    private static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String DNA = "ACTG";
        
        int choice = 5;
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 0: // all alpha numeric
                System.out.println(generateRandomString(10, DATA_FOR_RANDOM_STRING));
                break;
             case 1: // only UpperCase
                System.out.println(generateRandomString(10, CHAR_UPPER));
                break;
             case 2: // only LowerCase
                System.out.println(generateRandomString(10, CHAR_LOWER));
                break;
             case 3: // only numbers
                System.out.println(generateRandomString(10, NUMBER));
                break;
             case 4: // only DNA
                System.out.println(generateRandomString(10, DNA));
                break;
             case 5: // in place string : choose only from "ibra"
                System.out.println(generateRandomString(10, "ibra"));
                break;
          default:
               System.out.println(" choose between 0 and 5");
        }
        
        
    }
    
    public static String generateRandomString(int length, String DataChars) 
    {
        if (length < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            
            int rndCharAt = random.nextInt(DataChars.length());
            char rndChar = DataChars.charAt(rndCharAt);

            sb.append(rndChar);

        }

        return sb.toString();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The missing link in your example is a mechanism to let the method know what group of characters to use when generating the random String. One option is to pass the relevant characters as a second argument to the generateRandomString function. The below does this via 2 structs:

1. CharacterGroup - A group of characters (currently passed in as a String but may be other mechanisms added if needed)
2. StandardGroups - An enum of the most common character groups (ex: lower case chars, numbers, etc) to improve usability.

An array of Character groups is passed to the generateRandomString function from which a random String can be assembled.

```
    private static final String NUMBER = "0123456789";
    private static final String CHAR_LOWER = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private static final String CHAR_UPPER = CHAR_LOWER.toUpperCase();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            System.out.println(generateRandomString(10, StandardGroups.LOWER_CHARS.getChars(), StandardGroups.UPPER_CHARS.getChars()));
    }

    public static String generateRandomString(int length, CharacterGroup... acceptedTypes)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
        if (length < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Length must be >= 0");
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){ sb.append(chooseRandom(acceptedTypes).randomChar()); }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public enum StandardGroups
    {
        LOWER_CHARS(new CharacterGroup(CHAR_LOWER)), UPPER_CHARS(new CharacterGroup(CHAR_UPPER)), NUMERICS(new CharacterGroup(NUMBER)), SYMBOLS(new CharacterGroup("!@#."));
        private final CharacterGroup validValues;
        StandardGroups(CharacterGroup validVals){ this.validValues = validVals; }
        public CharacterGroup getChars(){ return validValues; }
    }

    public static final class CharacterGroup
    {
        private final String validValues;
        CharacterGroup(String validValues){ this.validValues = validValues; }
        public char[] getValidVals(){ return validValues.toCharArray(); }
        public char randomChar(){ return validValues.charAt(RANDOM.nextInt(validValues.length())); }
    }

    private static <T> T chooseRandom(T[] data){ if(data.length == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Length must be > 0"); return data[RANDOM.nextInt(data.length)]; }
    private static final SecureRandom RANDOM = new SecureRandom();
```